# How to add outer shadow to an uitabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

I use a UITabBarController in my iOS app. The above image show how the should look like. So my question is how can i make that outer shadow for the uitabbar? I have a UITabBarController. Here is my code for my UITabBarController so far:

```
import UIKit


class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.selectedIndex = 3
        self.delegate = self

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(CGColor: "#6eb18c".CGColor)
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"tabbarBackground.png")


        let selectedBG = UIImage(named:"tabbarBg.png")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = selectedBG

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            print("tabbed index 0")
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: did you found something to do it? Maybe without uiimage